# unique jquery object

Tags: jquery

A plugin which I need to implement in other website uses some jquery functions.
The website may or maynot be use jquery.
Is it possible to use my own jquery to my functions without affected by already called frameworks (jquery,prototype)?
The use of jQuery.noConflict() function affect the other functions used in the website.

Comment: You mean you want to use multiple versions of jQuery in a single page?

Comment: my code is inserting in to the existing site. so the jquery functions  i am using does not affected by the existing site and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

register your jQuery if it is not contain in the page. see the sample.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
         document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='Path To jQuery' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      }
</script>
```

Comment: if the site was already jquery registered , if we use noConflict() functions in the site may not work. if we use $ conflict may occur.

Comment: if site already having jQuery, you don't need to worry about conflict. because we are not registering jQuery again.so if it is conflicting it is already conflicted. so better to use jQuery instead of $.

Comment: Better solution, though I would append a `<script>` element to the head element instead of using document.write (as if this for instance runs from a bookmarklet, you would erase all other content in the site.

Comment: You're not registering JQuery again, but you are registering JQuery in the first place. If this script is before the 'real' JQuery is loaded, this version will be used instead of the version the website builder intended. Just don't do it, don't go including JQuery from your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the following in mind:

1. Don't include JQuery from your script.
2. Just expect JQuery to be included. Website builders can do this when they include your script.
3. Don't rely on the `$` global variable. It doesn't need to exist, and if it does, it doesn't need to point to JQuery. That's exactly what the `noConflict` method is for.

Comment: If you make sure you don't rely on the global `$` variable, it doesn't matter whether `noConflict` is used or not. It will always work if you use the `JQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: That will fail if the site depends on a different version of jQuery then the one required by the plugin.

Comment: Then fix the plugin. Before you know you will have 10 versions of JQuery, making your site slow and bloated. It's not that the difference between JQuery versions is so big that you would have much trouble updating. Usually you can upgrade without any problems at all, and if you do have problems, updating the code itself it altogether better that loading the whole library twice. I can't see why people even consider this an option.

Answer (score -1):

```
var old_$ = window.$;
var old_jQuery = window.jQuery;
// load jQuery
(function($) {
    // your script
})(jQuery);
window.$ = old_$;
window.jQuery = old_jQuery;
```

Comment: Wrapping the script in a function is a way to use scripts that require the `$` variable. Saving the references to JQuery in 'old' variables should not be necessary, though. Your script should not modify these variables.

Comment: jQuery modifies these variables at the moment it is loaded. You could use `$.noConflict(true)` to restore them, but it is easier to understand this way.